# Array and variables in mail message

Tags: mysql, email, message

I have the follow problem. I like to have some lines, max 10 in a message body. the lines I get from a database. How i can do it? Here my code I have. With echo, I get the "lines" but how i can put this in variable, I like to use in my mail message body?

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM multi_booking WHERE booking_no = '{$_GET['booking']}'";             
                        $ergebnis_sub = mysql_query($sql);

                        while ($row_sub = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis_sub))
                                    {
                                        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM multi_orders WHERE booking_no = '{$_GET['booking']}'";
                                        $result = mysql_query($sql1);
                                        $row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
                                        for($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++) 
                                        { 
                                            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
                                            echo("Service[$i]. {$row['Services']}\n");
                                        }

                                        $idbooking  = $row_sub->idbooking;
                                        $name  = $row_sub->name;
                                        $email  = $row_sub->email;
                                        $blang  = $row_sub->lang;
                                        $country  = $row_sub->country;
                                        $arrivaldate  = $row_sub->arrivaldate;
                                        $accommodation  = $row_sub->accommodation;
                                        $totalamount  = $row_sub->totalamount;
                                        $invoice  = $row_sub->invoice;
                                        $comment = $row_sub->comment;

                                        $message2 = "
                                        Subject: Booking $invoice<br />
                                        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />
                                        Name: $name<br />
                                        EMail: $email<br />
                                        Language: $blang<br />
                                        Country: $country<br />
                                        Arrival Date: $arrivaldate<br />
                                        Hotel: $accommodation<br />
                                        Service 1: '$service[1]'<br />
                                        Service 2: $service[2]<br />
                                        Service 3: $service[3]<br />
                                        Service 4: $service4<br />
                                        Service 5: $service5<br />
                                        Service 6: $service6<br />
                                        Service 7: $service7<br />
                                        Service 8: $service8<br />
                                        Service 9: $service9<br />
                                        Service 10: $service10<br />
                                        Total amount: $totalamount<br />
                                        Booking Invoice: $invoice<br />
                                        Booking Comment: $comment<br />
                                        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />

                                        Please check in the admin section for the follow booking number: $invoice

                                        ";

                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings with the `.` operator, so you can combine them like this into a single variable.

```
$lines = "";
for($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++) 
{ 
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
  $lines = $lines . "Service[$i]. {$row['Services']}\n");
}
```

Then you can combine those lines with the message like you did with the other variables.

```
$message2 = "
Subject: Booking $invoice<br />
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />
Name: $name<br />
EMail: $email<br />
Language: $blang<br />
Country: $country<br />
Arrival Date: $arrivaldate<br />
$lines
Total amount: $totalamount<br />
Booking Invoice: $invoice<br />
Booking Comment: $comment<br />";
```

You can also use the shorthand `.=`, just as you can use `+=` to add something to a variable. The two lines below are equal:

```
$mystring = $mystring . 'x';
$mystring .= 'x';
```

Comment: Hi GolezTrol

As far it work's as I like to have it. Is it possible to get "Service"  in one line?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: At the moment I get this in my email:
Services: Service[1]: Koh Tao (fueraborda) / Pax: 2 / Total: 9900 Service[2]: Snorkel en Angthong Marine Park / Pax: 2 / Total: 4600
everything in one line.
I prefer to have it in 2 or depend how many services lines.

Comment: Ah. I think you need to add a `<br />` as well in the for loop. Currently, there is only a `\n`, but in an HTML mail, that won't show.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can upvote and/or accept the answer to show this to future visitors.